# How to programmatically determine installed audio applications on Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to programmatically determine what audio applications are installed on an Android phone. I'm able to enumerate all the installed applications, but don't yet see a way to figure out which ones are capable of playing audio? What property of the application would have to queried to determine if is capable of playing audio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a starting point, can you post the code where you're enumerating all installed applications?

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to [queryIntentActivites][1] with an [ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with the MIME type specified as whatever form of audio you're playing.

[1]:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent, int)